# Theorem 10.2 Rudin

Tags: abstract-algebra, integration, analysis, continuity

[image]

[image]

$\mathscr b(X)$ denotes the set of all complex-valued, continuous, bounded functions with domain $X$.

I don't understand why is $L(h)$ equal of $\prod_{i=1}^k $ $\int_{a_i}^{b_i} h_i(x_i)dx_i$ and then why it's equal of $L'(h)$. As I know $\int f(x)g(x)dx$ is not equal of $\int f(x) dx \int g(x) dx $.

The proof of is theorem is absolutely ununderstandable for me.
I also  don't understand why is $L(g)$ equal of $L'(g)$ for all $ g $ $\in$ $\mathscr A $.

I would be grateful for any kind of help

Answer (score 1):

The proof doesn't use that $\int_{}f(x)g(x)~dx = \int_{}f(x)dx \int_{}g(x)dx$ (which is wrong), but rather $$\int_{}\int_{}f(x)g(y)~dxdy = \int_{}g(y) \int_{}f(x)dx ~dy = \int_{}f(x)~dx\int_{}g(y)dy.$$
Note that this follows simply from the property that $\int_{}C f(x)dx = C\int_{}f(x)dx$, where in the first equality we set $C = g(y)$ to pull out $g(y)$ from the inner integral as it does not depend on $x$, then in the second step we use that $C:= \int_{}f(x)dx$ does not depend on $y$ to pull it out of the integral with respect to $y$. By symmetry, this reasoning also shows that
$$\int_{}\int_{}f(x)g(y)~dxdy = \int_{}\int_{}f(x)g(y)~dydx.$$
and therefore with $h(x,y) := f(x)g(y)$ it follows that $L(h) = L'(h)$. The general case with the product of $k$ functions is completely analogous and can be shown e.g. by induction. Now note that $L$ and $L'$ are *linear* operators, that is, it holds that $$L(\alpha h_1 + \beta h_2) = \alpha L(h_1) + \beta L(h_2), \quad L'(\alpha h_1 + \beta h_2) = \alpha L'(h_1) + \beta L'(h_2),$$
where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $h_1,h_2$ are continuous functions. In particular, since $L(h) = L'(h)$ for any $h$ of product form, it follows that $L(g) = L'(g)$ for any $g \in \mathcal{A}$: consider for example the case that $g = \alpha h_1 + \beta h_2$, where $h_1,h_2$ are of product form. Then, the fact that $L(h_1) = L'(h_1)$ and $L(h_2) = L'(h_2)$ and the linearity yield
\begin{align*} L(g) &= L(\alpha h_1 + \beta h_2) =  \alpha L(h_1) + \beta L(h_2) = \alpha L'(h_1) + \beta L'(h_2) \\
&= L'(\alpha h_1 + \beta h_2) = L'(g).
\end{align*}

Comment: thanks for that. please I will have another question. how do we know that there exists $ g \ in \mathscr A $ such that $||f-g||$ < $\epsilon$/V ?

Comment: @SerIsaac that is a consequence of the Stone-Weierstraß theorem. Since $\mathcal{A}$ is a subalgebra of the continuous functions that contains $1$ and separates points, it lies dense in the space of continuous functions.

Comment: What do you mean in " that contains $1$ " ?

Comment: it means that the function that the constant function that is equal to $1$ everywhere is an element of $\mathcal{A}$.